# Exchange W3WP Memory usage for MSExchangePowerShellAppPool and MSExchangeECPAppPool

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I have a number of W3WP processes running. Consuming excessive amount of memory. It doesn't seem normal.

- One process is for **MSExchangePowerShellAppPool and is using average
  1.1GB of ram**.  Making it second highest memory hog behind store.exe
- Second process is for **MSExchangeECPAppPool and is using average of
  500mb of ram**.

2008 r2

Exchange 2010

14 databases

Average DB Size range from 30gb to 80gb

**Any thoughts from someone with similar system?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what your question is...especially if the question is "is this normal" since everyone's environment is somewhat unique.

However,

For me, with Exchange 2010, 2008R, 8 databases with sizes between 30GB and 300GB:

Edge Transport is right behind store.exe @ 745MB.

MSExchangePowerShellAppPool is right behind that @ 560MB.

MsExchangeECPAppPool is right behind that @ 375MB.

So if that helps gauge your answer...great!

Comment: It does, it indicates to me that those two app pools are using a excessive amount of ram. From my experience they use much less.

Comment: Would like to add that recycling the Application Pools in IIS for those two services fixed the problem.